# How set root node from an array itslef

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a flat array as below:

```
var array = [{"id":"a","root":"a","parent":" "},
{"id":"a.001","root":"a","parent":"a"},
{"id":"a.001.001","root":"a","parent":"a.001"},
{"id":"a.001.001.001","root":"a","parent":"a.001.001"},
{"id":"a.001.001.001.001","root":"a","parent":"a.001.001.001"},
{"id":"a.001.001.001.002","root":"a","parent":"a.001.001.001"},
{"id":"a.001.001.001.003","root":"a","parent":"a.001.001.001"},
{"id":"a.001.001.001.004","root":"a","parent":"a.001.001.001"},
{"id":"a.001.001.002","root":"a","parent":"a.001.001"},
{"id":"a.001.001.002.001","root":"a","parent":"a.001.001.002"},
{"id":"a.001.001.002.002","root":"a","parent":"a.001.001.002"},
{"id":"a.001.001.002.003","root":"a","parent":"a.001.001.002"},
{"id":"a.001.001.002.004","root":"a","parent":"a.001.001.002"},
{"id":"a.001.001.003","root":"a","parent":"a.001.001"},
{"id":"a.001.001.003.001","root":"a","parent":"a.001.001.003"},
{"id":"a.001.001.003.002","root":"a","parent":"a.001.001.003"},
{"id":"a.001.001.003.003","root":"a","parent":"a.001.001.003"},
{"id":"a.001.001.003.004","root":"a","parent":"a.001.001.003"},
{"id":"a.001.002","root":"a","parent":"a.001"},
{"id":"a.001.002.001","root":"a","parent":"a.001.002"},
{"id":"a.001.002.002","root":"a","parent":"a.001.002"},
{"id":"a.001.002.003","root":"a","parent":"a.001.002"},
{"id":"a.001.003","root":"a","parent":"a.001"},
{"id":"a.001.003.001","root":"a","parent":"a.001.003"},
{"id":"a.001.003.002","root":"a","parent":"a.001.003"},
{"id":"a.001.004","root":"a","parent":"a.001"},
{"id":"a.001.004.001","root":"a","parent":"a.001.004"},
{"id":"a.001.004.002","root":"a","parent":"a.001.004"},
{"id":"a.001.004.003","root":"a","parent":"a.001.004"},
{"id":"a.001.004.004","root":"a","parent":"a.001.004"}
]
```

Now I have converted this flat array into tree array using the below code.

```js
var array=[{"id":"a","root":"a","parent":" "},{"id":"a.001","root":"a","parent":"a"},{"id":"a.001.001","root":"a","parent":"a.001"},{"id":"a.001.001.001","root":"a","parent":"a.001.001"},{"id":"a.001.001.001.001","root":"a","parent":"a.001.001.001"},{"id":"a.001.001.001.002","root":"a","parent":"a.001.001.001"},{"id":"a.001.001.001.003","root":"a","parent":"a.001.001.001"},{"id":"a.001.001.001.004","root":"a","parent":"a.001.001.001"},{"id":"a.001.001.002","root":"a","parent":"a.001.001"},{"id":"a.001.001.002.001","root":"a","parent":"a.001.001.002"},{"id":"a.001.001.002.002","root":"a","parent":"a.001.001.002"},{"id":"a.001.001.002.003","root":"a","parent":"a.001.001.002"},{"id":"a.001.001.002.004","root":"a","parent":"a.001.001.002"},{"id":"a.001.001.003","root":"a","parent":"a.001.001"},{"id":"a.001.001.003.001","root":"a","parent":"a.001.001.003"},{"id":"a.001.001.003.002","root":"a","parent":"a.001.001.003"},{"id":"a.001.001.003.003","root":"a","parent":"a.001.001.003"},{"id":"a.001.001.003.004","root":"a","parent":"a.001.001.003"},{"id":"a.001.002","root":"a","parent":"a.001"},{"id":"a.001.002.001","root":"a","parent":"a.001.002"},{"id":"a.001.002.002","root":"a","parent":"a.001.002"},{"id":"a.001.002.003","root":"a","parent":"a.001.002"},{"id":"a.001.003","root":"a","parent":"a.001"},{"id":"a.001.003.001","root":"a","parent":"a.001.003"},{"id":"a.001.003.002","root":"a","parent":"a.001.003"},{"id":"a.001.004","root":"a","parent":"a.001"},{"id":"a.001.004.001","root":"a","parent":"a.001.004"},{"id":"a.001.004.002","root":"a","parent":"a.001.004"},{"id":"a.001.004.003","root":"a","parent":"a.001.004"},{"id":"a.001.004.004","root":"a","parent":"a.001.004"}]

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

  array[i].children = [];
}

function tree(array) {

  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array.forEach(function(n) {
      if (n.parent === array[i].id) {
        array[i].children.push(n);

      }

    });
  }


  return array.filter(function(n) {
    return n.parent === "";
  });
}
var fdata = tree(array);

console.log(fdata);
```

I would like to make "a" (from the root) as the root node of the above tree array.

Please let me how to do it.

[image]

Regards,

Teja.

Comment: Please provide valid array (id must be string, i think)

Comment: You want {id : a, root: a, parent : ” “}, this to be the root node?

Comment: No, only 'a' from the 'root' to be the root node of the tree array.

Comment: @AlexOwl...Done the changes. Thanks

Comment: Captain here, @AlexOwl I fixed it with some regex ;)

Comment: Any other suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 1):

For your case, I would go with lodash:

```
const _ = require('lodash');

var array=[{"id":"a","root":"a","parent":" "},{"id":"a.001","root":"a","parent":"a"},{"id":"a.001.001","root":"a","parent":"a.001"},{"id":"a.001.001.001","root":"a","parent":"a.001.001"},{"id":"a.001.001.001.001","root":"a","parent":"a.001.001.001"},{"id":"a.001.001.001.002","root":"a","parent":"a.001.001.001"},{"id":"a.001.001.001.003","root":"a","parent":"a.001.001.001"},{"id":"a.001.001.001.004","root":"a","parent":"a.001.001.001"},{"id":"a.001.001.002","root":"a","parent":"a.001.001"},{"id":"a.001.001.002.001","root":"a","parent":"a.001.001.002"},{"id":"a.001.001.002.002","root":"a","parent":"a.001.001.002"},{"id":"a.001.001.002.003","root":"a","parent":"a.001.001.002"},{"id":"a.001.001.002.004","root":"a","parent":"a.001.001.002"},{"id":"a.001.001.003","root":"a","parent":"a.001.001"},{"id":"a.001.001.003.001","root":"a","parent":"a.001.001.003"},{"id":"a.001.001.003.002","root":"a","parent":"a.001.001.003"},{"id":"a.001.001.003.003","root":"a","parent":"a.001.001.003"},{"id":"a.001.001.003.004","root":"a","parent":"a.001.001.003"},{"id":"a.001.002","root":"a","parent":"a.001"},{"id":"a.001.002.001","root":"a","parent":"a.001.002"},{"id":"a.001.002.002","root":"a","parent":"a.001.002"},{"id":"a.001.002.003","root":"a","parent":"a.001.002"},{"id":"a.001.003","root":"a","parent":"a.001"},{"id":"a.001.003.001","root":"a","parent":"a.001.003"},{"id":"a.001.003.002","root":"a","parent":"a.001.003"},{"id":"a.001.004","root":"a","parent":"a.001"},{"id":"a.001.004.001","root":"a","parent":"a.001.004"},{"id":"a.001.004.002","root":"a","parent":"a.001.004"},{"id":"a.001.004.003","root":"a","parent":"a.001.004"},{"id":"a.001.004.004","root":"a","parent":"a.001.004"}]

const newStructure = {};
array.forEach(item => {
    newItem = {};
    _.set(newItem, item.id, {});
    _.merge(newStructure, newItem);
})

console.log(newStructure);
```

This will have this output

```
{ a:
   { '001':
      { '001': [Object],
        '002': [Object],
        '003': [Object],
        '004': [Object] } } }
```

Or FE version:

```html
<script src="https:////cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>

<script>

    var array=[{"id":"a","root":"a","parent":" "},{"id":"a.001","root":"a","parent":"a"},{"id":"a.001.001","root":"a","parent":"a.001"},{"id":"a.001.001.001","root":"a","parent":"a.001.001"},{"id":"a.001.001.001.001","root":"a","parent":"a.001.001.001"},{"id":"a.001.001.001.002","root":"a","parent":"a.001.001.001"},{"id":"a.001.001.001.003","root":"a","parent":"a.001.001.001"},{"id":"a.001.001.001.004","root":"a","parent":"a.001.001.001"},{"id":"a.001.001.002","root":"a","parent":"a.001.001"},{"id":"a.001.001.002.001","root":"a","parent":"a.001.001.002"},{"id":"a.001.001.002.002","root":"a","parent":"a.001.001.002"},{"id":"a.001.001.002.003","root":"a","parent":"a.001.001.002"},{"id":"a.001.001.002.004","root":"a","parent":"a.001.001.002"},{"id":"a.001.001.003","root":"a","parent":"a.001.001"},{"id":"a.001.001.003.001","root":"a","parent":"a.001.001.003"},{"id":"a.001.001.003.002","root":"a","parent":"a.001.001.003"},{"id":"a.001.001.003.003","root":"a","parent":"a.001.001.003"},{"id":"a.001.001.003.004","root":"a","parent":"a.001.001.003"},{"id":"a.001.002","root":"a","parent":"a.001"},{"id":"a.001.002.001","root":"a","parent":"a.001.002"},{"id":"a.001.002.002","root":"a","parent":"a.001.002"},{"id":"a.001.002.003","root":"a","parent":"a.001.002"},{"id":"a.001.003","root":"a","parent":"a.001"},{"id":"a.001.003.001","root":"a","parent":"a.001.003"},{"id":"a.001.003.002","root":"a","parent":"a.001.003"},{"id":"a.001.004","root":"a","parent":"a.001"},{"id":"a.001.004.001","root":"a","parent":"a.001.004"},{"id":"a.001.004.002","root":"a","parent":"a.001.004"},{"id":"a.001.004.003","root":"a","parent":"a.001.004"},{"id":"a.001.004.004","root":"a","parent":"a.001.004"}]
    
    const newStructure = {};
    array.forEach(item => {
        newItem = {};
        _.set(newItem, item.id, {});
        _.merge(newStructure, newItem);
    })
    
    console.log(newStructure);

</script>
```

(The console log only logs to certain depth to not spend too much resources or get in some kind of circular issue, but there is full structure of what you have)
To see full structure, you can add this

```
const util = require('util')
console.log(util.inspect(newStructure, {showHidden: false, depth: null}))
```

Then you will get this:

```
{ a:
   { '001':
      { '001':
         { '001': { '001': {}, '002': {}, '003': {}, '004': {} },
           '002': { '001': {}, '002': {}, '003': {}, '004': {} },
           '003': { '001': {}, '002': {}, '003': {}, '004': {} } },
        '002': { '001': {}, '002': {}, '003': {} },
        '003': { '001': {}, '002': {} },
        '004': { '001': {}, '002': {}, '003': {}, '004': {} } } } }
```

Comment: But I need code in Javascript ...seems above is from node.js...Could you please let me know the other options. I am getting an error: require is not defined. Thank you @libik

Comment: @user1700650 - just check the lodash official page: https://lodash.com/ you can download it and reference it with `<script src="lodash.js"></script>`

Comment: I used this code:<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash-fp/0.10.4/lodash-fp.js">
</script>
 const _ = require('lodash');

var array = [......];
const newStructure = {};
array.forEach(item => {
    newItem = {};
    _.set(newItem, item.id, {});
    _.merge(newStructure, newItem);
})

console.log(newStructure); ...But got nothing.@libik

Comment: But with the above method strings got separated. I mean a.001 is divided into two parts it seems a and 001. I need it in the form of a.001.001 etc...one more thing is:"id":"a.001","root":"a","parent":"a", I want to set 'a' from root:a;..Thanks a lot for your previous responses.

Comment: Your code worked for me after a few modifications...please suggest the code to get the output along with a..for example a.001, a.001.001 etc apart from just oo1, 002 etc. Thank you